# Function type does not match the function definition

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran, writing some practice code with a function that returns Farenheit from Celsius

```
program Console1

implicit none
real, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(p=15)
real (kind = ikind):: c,f,o,faren
print *, "enter a temperature in degrees celsius"
read *, c
write(*,10) "farenheit =", faren(c) 
10   format(a,f10.8)

end program Console1



function faren(c)

real, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(p=15)
real (kind = ikind):: c,f   
faren = (9/5)*c + 32

end function faren
```

I get an error #7977 : The type of the function reference does not match the type of the function definition.

So with that if i change `function faren(c)` to `real function faren(c)`
I get the same error, but the types are the same?

Am i missing something? Do I have to define the function in the main program?

Comment: Adding `implicit none` to the function's body gives you a good hint which you partly pick up on with `real function faren`.  Your compiler is saying that `real` and `real(kind=ikind)` are not the same.  Have the definitions consistent and things are fine.  [Having an explicit interface available helps here: see about modules and internal functions.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues in addition to the structural/code arrangement ones already noted.

First, `KIND` is an integer, so you want to change

```
real, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(p=15)
```

to

```
integer, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(p=15)
```

Ideally, you want to define that in only one place (i.e. in a module) and reference it from both your main program and the function, but the code should be fine as it is for test purposes.

A second issue that often trips up newcomers to Fortran (and Python2) is that real numbers and integers are distinct types and are not generally interchangeable.

```
faren = (9/5)*c + 32
```

simplifies to

```
faren = (1)*c + 32
```

because integer division has an integer result; 9/5 = 1

Fortran is picky about numerical values (that's sort of the whole point of the language) so what you probably want is:

```
faren = (9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32.0
```

Or more precisely, if `faren` is defined with a specific precision of `ikind`,

```
faren = (real(9.0,ikind) / real_(5.0,ikind)) * c + real(32.0,ikind)
```

or

```
faren = (9.0_ikind / 5.0_ikind) * c + 32.0_ikind
```

This syntax tends to make people's heads explode. Welcome to modern fortran ;)

The last issue deals with the horrors of Fortran I/O. From a design standpoint, you need to know what results the user expects and make sure the output format can display them. The legitimate range of input values for `c` is -273.15 (give or take) to some upper bound which relies on the use case for the code. If you're dealing with cooking temperatures, you probably won't exceed 400.0; if you're doing fusion research, you could be going much higher. Are 8 figures past the decimal useful or believable? In this case, we're just testing the code so we may not need a lot of precision in the output; you'll want to change the output format to something like:

```
10   format(a,es10.2)
```

or

```
10   format(a,g16.8)
```

You need to ensure the total field width (the number before the dot) can contain the decimal part (the number after the dot) along with the integer part of the number, plus the space needed to show sign and exponent. For scientific notation, four characters are eaten by mantissa sign, decimal point, 'E' and exponent sign. It may be safer just starting out to use an output format of `*`; it's frustrating to fight with numerics and formatting simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good effort and simple start to work through the nuance, so a good question.

Personally I would use reals for the math, rather the 9/5, and use a module. In this example you could pass in a real or a double to C2Faren and the interface/procedure will sort out whether to use the real or the double version. Then you have a few options in case you want different precision.

You could also use the ISO_C_BINDING if you do mixed language...

```
MODULE MyTEMPS
PRIVATE
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: C2F_ScaleFact = 1.8D0
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: F2C_ScaleFact = /(1.0D0 / 1.8D0)/
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: F2C_Offset    = 32.0D0
PUBLIC Faren2C

INTERFACE C2Faren
  MODULE PROCEDURE C2Faren_Real, C2Faren_DBL
END INTERFACE

CONTAINS

!========= REAL VERISON =========
REAL FUNCTION C2Faren_Real(c)
IMPLICIT NONE
real, INTENT(IN   ) ::  c

C2Faren_Real = ( C*F2C_ScaleFact ) + F2C_Offset

RETURN
END FUNCTION C2Faren_Real

!========= DOUBLE VERSION =========
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION C2Faren_DBL(c)
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION , INTENT(IN   ) ::  c

C2Faren_DBL = ( C*F2C_ScaleFact ) + F2C_Offset

RETURN
END FUNCTION C2Faren_DBL

!========= REAL VERSION (Faren to Centigrade) =========
REAL FUNCTION faren2C(Faren)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, INTENT(IN   ) :: Faren

faren2C = (faren - F2C_Offset) / F2C_ScaleFact

RETURN
END FUNCTION faren2C

END MODULE MyTEMPS
```

Then your program uses the module via USE n the second line...

```
program Console1
USE MyTEMPS          !<== Here
implicit none
real   ::  c, f
DOUBLE PRECISION ::  Dc, Df   ! No way to get Df to C or DC in the module (yet)!
print *, "enter a temperature in degrees celsius"
read *, c
write(*,10) "farenheit =", C2faren(c) 
10   format(a,f10.6)

Dc = C
write(*,12) "farenheit =", C2faren(Dc) 
12   format("DBL:",A,f10.6)

F = Dc
write(*,14) "Centigrade =", faren2C(F) 
14   format("DBL:",A,f10.6)

end program Console1
```

So/and the main advantage of the module is when you end up wanting to use this stuff in a variety of programs and test and sort out the module once... Usually people put this sort of stuff (lots of modules) in a library, when the module(s) have lot of functions.

You could also put just the real, parameter :: ikind = selected_real_kind(p=15) into a module and use that in both the program and the function and you would be there. You were real close, and it mostly a matter of style and utility.

For Intel Fortran you can use REAL(KIND=4) and REAL(KIND=8)... Which I do, but that is not portable to gfortran, so it is probably a better habit to use the ISO_C_BINDING or just use REAL and DOUBLE PRECISION.

Comment: *it is probably a better habit to use the ISO_C_BINDING*  Well, for mixed-language programming perhaps.  Maybe better to advise a beginner to use the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env` and the kind types it contains, such as `real64` and `int32`.

Comment: Good point @HighPerformanceMark I need to change a lot of ifort code to allow gfortran compilation, so it is a good reminder to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are great but if you have a very simple code another way to work is to put the subroutines and functions in your main program.  The trick is to put them after the word contains:

```
program xxx
stuff

contains

subroutine yyy
function zzz

end program xxx
```

In this way the functions can see into the contents of the main program so you don't have to re-declare your parameters and you are likely to get more meaningful error messages.

Since you are new I have a great resource I learned a lot from to share:
http://www.uv.es/dogarcar/man/IntrFortran90.pdf